# Python Tkinter remove/delete Image from Label

Tags: python, image, tkinter, label

I have a label with an image, and a button which should update the label / delete the image in the label, so I can put a new image into the same label via label.config.

I tryed to use something like that: whenever you click on the button the it should remove the image with label.config(image = None) but it doesnt work, if I load new images into the label the old ones are still there:

```
    # here is the label initialized 
    global brand_preview
    brand_preview = Label(root, image = None)
    brand_preview.place(x = 10, y = 60)

    # thats the button which have to clear the label image
    self.top_brand = Button(root, text = "clear", bg = "snow3", command=clear_label_image)
    self.top_brand.place(x = 550, y = 60)

    # thats how I load a photoimage into the label
    photoimg_brand = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im_thumb)
    brand_preview.image = photoimg_brand
    brand_preview.config(image = photoimg_brand)

    # Thats how the button works
    def clear_label_image():
        brand_preview.config(image = None)
        brand_preview.image = None
```

All I want now that if we I click the Button the brand_preview loses the image / the image gets deleted

EDIT:
The main issue is solved, but that only works if the button only has to delete the image. If I want to delete and add a new one it doesnt work

```
def clear_label_image():
    brand_preview.config(image = "")
    photoimg_brand = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im_thumb)
    brand_preview.image = photoimg_brand
    brand_preview.config(image = photoimg_brand)
```

Comment: Please post a minimal example with runnable code that displays the behavior you want to fix.

Comment: Are you saving a reference to the new image? In your new code, `photoimg_brand` will get garbage-collected and disappear as soon as `clear_label_image()` completes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're very close - the `image` parameter just needs an empty string rather than `None`.

```
def clear_label_image():
    brand_preview.config(image='')
```

Comment: Thanks that works if the Button has to delete it, but somehow if I add new Image after it the old one is again there, thats weird!

Comment: What do you mean, the old one is there?

Comment: if the Button first has to clean the label and then give it a new image, then the old one comes back / is still there. All in all im trying to create a preview window. We have 2 Buttons that do the same, clean label and display an image on top or bottom of the label. If I click this button it has to remove the top image and update it with a new (the bot image). But I guess I can figure it out alone, you helped me alot already.

Comment: There should be only 0 or 1 images in the label. I'm not seeing anything like the behavior you're describing.

Comment: Okay, thats probably my problem, all the code is really long so i tried to post only relevant parts, but I have probably to work with Canvas. Atm I am drawing another label ontop of a label so I have main label + small label on top of the main label. I update the images in the small label with this button, so they appear bottom or top of the main label.

Answer (score 1):

After some Googling, I found this solution

```
def clear_label_image():
    #brand_preview.config(image = None)
    brand_preview.image.blank()
    brand_preview.image = None
```

This definitely clears the image from the button.  I haven't tried changing to a new image.

I just copied it from the Web, and it worked.  I created the image with

```
photoimg_brand = tk.PhotoImage(file='/usr/share/httpd/icons/world1.gif')
```

I did this with python 2.7, and my only import was `import Tkinter as tk`

Comment: where does blank comes from? Its an unkown attribute

Comment: @RomanDammer I updated my answer, but I'm sorry to say I don't have very good information for you.  I see you used ImageTk to create the PhotoImage.  That's probably the difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `label` to show the image then you can do this:

```
label.pack_forget()
```

`label` should be global

Comment: HI katt, welcome on Stack Overflow. Please use proper english.