# Basic Photo file sorter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm currently working as an undergrad intern engineer and am looking to streamline the file sorting process for those at my workplace. I am attempting to make a python program that displays an image  and has buttons below than when pressed move that photo into a specific folder.

The biggest difficulty so far is that I have no experience with python but that is what the company uses so im locked into it. I am able to create a messy program that displays a window with a photo and am yet to add buttons but that should be alright. My current concern is that it opens a new window every time it sorts a photo, as if the window is the photo rather than the photo being a part of the window. I will post my messy code below but any help would be appreciated. Please keep in mind im a complete python beginner, my only experience similar to this is in C#.

```
import os
import shutil
import tkinter as tk
import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

source = 'C:\\Source\\'  


for file in os.listdir(source):
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("1920x1080")
    photo = Image.open(source+file).resize((750,500), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(photo)
    panel = tk.Label(root, image = img)
    panel.image = img
    panel.pack(side = "top", fill = "both")
    print('Enter Destination Directory')
    dest = input()
    shutil.move(source+file, dest)
    root.destroy()
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be opening new windows because you are destroying root.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define and destroy your `root` variable outside of your main `for` loop. Each time you loop, you create a new `tk.Tk` object and then, destroy it.

Comment: In that case, with the root outside the loop it adds the next photo to the window rather then replace the previous one. Is there a way to refresh the image file so it updates to the next image in the list?

Comment: @BradyGale - Does this link help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33302779/python-tkinter-remove-delete-image-from-label